# How do I append values of a custom metric from a custom Callback to "logs" which I need to use in tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback

I need to implement a custom callback to calculate AUC after every epoch, which I need to use as a metric in LSTM based neural network. This is the custom callback:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
class RocCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self,training_data,validation_data):
        self.x = training_data[0]
        self.y = training_data[1]
        self.x_val = validation_data[0]
        self.y_val = validation_data[1]

        

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.roc_train_list = []
        self.roc_val_list = []
        self.roc_train=0
        self.roc_val=0
        logs["roc_train"] = []
        logs["roc_val"] = []
        return 


    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        y_pred_train = self.model.predict(self.x)
        roc_train = roc_auc_score(self.y, y_pred_train)
        y_pred_val = self.model.predict(self.x_val)
        roc_val = roc_auc_score(self.y_val, y_pred_val)
        #print('\rroc-auc_train: %s - roc-auc_val: %s' % (str(round(roc_train,4)),str(round(roc_val,4))),end=100*' '+'\n')
        
        # self.history['roc_auc_train'].append(round(roc_train,4))

        # self.history['roc_auc_val'].append(round(roc_val,4))
        self.roc_train = round(roc_train,4)
        self.roc_val = round(roc_val,4) 
        self.roc_train_list.append(self.roc_train)
        self.roc_val_list.append(self.roc_val)
        print("\rroc_train: %f — roc_val: %f" %(self.roc_train, self.roc_val))
        
        logs["roc_train"]= self.roc_train
        logs["roc_val"] = self.roc_val

        return logs
```

There are two things which aren't working properly:

1. The `print("\rroc_train: %f — roc_val: %f" %(self.roc_train, self.roc_val))` prints *just before* the epoch progress bar but it needs to print *just after*
   e.g.:

```
Epoch 2/20
roc_train: 0.550000 — roc_val: 0.547800
2561/2561 [==============================] - 89s 35ms/step - loss: 0.5326 - val_loss: 0.4513
Epoch 3/20
roc_train: 0.559800 — roc_val: 0.558000
2561/2561 [==============================] - 88s 34ms/step - loss: 0.5049 - val_loss: 0.4406
```

2. The logs in tensorboard only has epoch_loss as metric but no "roc_train" or "roc_val" values.
   I have tried

```
logs["roc_train"].append(self.roc_train)
logs["roc_val"].append(self.roc_val)
```

but it raises a Key Error.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick alternative, have you tried using the built-in `https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC`, metric,

```
tf.keras.metrics.AUC(
    num_thresholds=200, curve='ROC', summation_method='interpolation', name=None,
    dtype=None, thresholds=None, multi_label=False, label_weights=None
)
```

it may solve for the moment your problem.

Your code is indeed not wrong; in the callbacks list in model.fit(), could you please place your callback in the first position in the list; in my case it happened that I wanted once to save to a .csv and the CustomMetric() callback was the last, therefore the .csv was saved only with loss and val_loss not with my custom metrics.

Comment: Part of the requirement of this task is that I need to use custom callback. I'd want to learn to get this right, anyway. Would be helpful in the long-run.

Comment: Did you do what I recommended in the last part of my answer?

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to mention about that. Yes, I did. I placed callbacks as the first argument in model.fit(). There were no changes to the result. 'logs' still just has epoch_loss.

Comment: What TensorFlow version are you using?

Comment: Hi, could you tell me something. If I use tf.keras.metrics.AUC, that would calculate AUC batchwise and not epoch-wise. For this reason, I tried using the custom callback. Any other way I could do this?

Comment: Hi sans_mist. Unfortunately there is no other way, because the way the final metric is calculated is by means of accumulation, and therefore there is no other way to access the batch_size level. At the same time I think it is a good thing that you are able to do this via a Callback function.

Comment: The custom callback is working. All I am not able to do is save the epoch-wise AUC scores in 'logs' so that I can use it to plot a scalar plot in tensorboard.. I guess at this point I'm repeating myself. Thanks for your time, really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Sad I couldn't help more, I strongly start to believe it's an odd bug of the latest TF version.

Comment: Could you check out the other question I've posted (about tf.summary.scalar)? I've made progress but need a little help..

Comment: @sans_mist I can confirm in TensorFlow 2.3 there is some problem, logs in my case is always empty.

Comment: You did? What did you do? I went forward with using matplotlib.pyplot to plot using tf.summary.scalar()